# ImportError: cannot import name '_docstring' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, importerror

I am trying to import matplotlib in .ipynb file but its not working, none of my files have the same name as _docstring yet I get this error and if I try something in .py file, it works fine.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv
```

I'm running this in a .ipynb file in VS Code

Output :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 import numpy as np 
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import cv2 as cv

File c:\Users\P****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:113
    109 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    111 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    112 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 113 from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
    114 from matplotlib.cbook import sanitize_sequence
    115 from matplotlib._api import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

ImportError: cannot import name '_docstring' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\P****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)
```

But if I try to import matplotlib in .py file like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,10,0.1)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

It runs fine, no issues.

Comment: What have you named your .ipynb file?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the matplotlib package resolved the issue.

pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall matplotlib

Comment: Please, format the command by surrounding it between ``` chatacters.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting matplotlib folder and reinstalling it.

Full path: AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\matplotlib

It worked for me.